# Shared Primary Key Associations for collections

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following entities:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    virtual public ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 TransactionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual User Sender {get; set;}

    public virtual User Receiver { get; set; }
}
```

The relationship is described in fluent API

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(r => r.Transactions)
            .WithRequired(s => s.Sender);

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(r => r.Transactions)
            .WithOptional(r => r.Receiver);
```

There are two users, one is a sender of the transaction the second is the receive.
Now when I add a transaction to the first user everything works. When the second user accepts the transaction and I add the same transaction to its ICollection of transactions it magically disappears from the first user and vise versa. In other words EF prevents me from referencing the same entity in both parents. Is there way around it ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have two navigation properties in your User Class.

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    virtual public ICollection<Transaction> SenderTransactions { get; set; }
    virtual public ICollection<Transaction> ReceiverTransactions { get; set; }
}
```

Each navigation property must have equivalent navigation property in related class.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(r => r.SenderTransactions)
            .WithRequired(s => s.Sender);

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(r => r.ReceiverTransactions)
            .WithOptional(r => r.Receiver);
```

Comment: That is perfect! Thanks. It worth noting that in this case setting the user as for example the sender of the transaction automatically adds this transaction to the reference list of that user without a need to do it manually.